# xml post as parameter for Objective C

Tags: objective-c, xml, post

How does one post xml as parameter with Objective C?

I've sent a username and a password in xml to the server. I've tried using `ASIFormDataRequest`. I've posted xml and the server've given the error that is "username or password is false". I think the server doesn't parse the posting xml. Is there any way to post xml as parameter?

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"url code"];

ASIFormDataRequest *request1 =[ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];

[request1 setPostValue:"xml block" forKey:@"data"];
[request1 addRequestHeader:@"Content-Type" value:@"application/xml;"];
[request1 setDelegate:self];
[request1 startSynchronous];
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. Look at my example:

```
    NSString *message = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" ?>\n<parameters></parameters>"];

    url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://https_url.com"];
    request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[message length]];

    [request addValue:@"application/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request addValue:msgLength                         forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setHTTPBody:[message dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [message release];
```

Comment: The xml must be posted as data="xml parameters" so I've tried using
[request1 setPostValue:"xml block" forKey:@"data"]. But this is not a solution. Any suggestion?

Comment: It's bad solution to send in xml in such way... Your content-type is not xml in such case... Try as I've descirbed

Comment: I need a key and a value (xml parameters) for  posting. How can I add "data" key in your code?

Comment: Replace in your code : `[request1 setPostValue:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" ?>\n<parameters></parameters>" forKey:@"data"];`

Comment: Yes, but your code is posted xml without key. The service I post uses xml with key.

Comment: Contact admin of that service.

Comment: I've posted same xml parameters to the service with Java and PHP so the service run correctly.